# Convert NSmangedObject to JsonModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, jsonmodel

In my application I am using a JsonModel for parsing JSON response from server and while storing it in Core Data I am using `NSManagedObject` and `NSManagedContext` which is provided by Apple itself. Now whenever I fetch I want to convert the `NSManagedObject` to JsonModel. Now the problem is I have to use two separate class to manage jsonModel and `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you. first try to convert your `NSMangedObject` to `NSDictionary`.

```
NSArray *keys = [[[yourObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
NSDictionary *dict = [myObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
```

the you have to use dict as a JSON or convert them into JSON string if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from this link.

[Get Core Data objects to JSON](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2365)

Or in easy way from [andrew-madsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344733/andrew-madsen)'s Answer

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = ...;
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", ..., nil]; // These are the keys for the properties of your managed object that you want in the JSON
NSString *json = [[managedObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys] JSONRepresentation];
```

For more detail try this link

[nsmanagedobject-to-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282739/nsmanagedobject-to-json)